# Why my form values are not being submitted in web2py?

Tags: html, web2py

I have a simple form for log in purposes. I am a beginner in using web2py so i cant figure out why my form values are not being submitted.

This my controller function

```
def signup():
   form = SQLFORM(db.Membership).process()
   form.add_button('Back', URL('index.html'))

   if form.process().accepted:
        session.flash = 'form accepted'
        redirect(URL('index.html'))
   elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'form has errors'
   else:
        response.flash = 'please fill the form'

   return locals()
```

This is my database

```
db.define_table('Membership',
    Field('userID', 'id'),
    Field('username', 'string',unique=True),
    Field('membershipType','string',default = "Member", label = T('Membership Type')),
    Field('name' , 'string',default='Admin'),
    Field('password', 'password'),
    Field('email' , 'string',default='Admin@admin.com'),
    Field('cNum', 'integer',, label = T('Contact Number'))
    )
```

and this is the html

```
<section>
    <h2>Fill in the details to register</h2>


    {{=form}}



</section>
```

Like i said i am only a beginner so if please give any help possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `form.process()` twice. The first call will actually do the processing and insert the record, and the second one will simply reset the CSRF token. As a result, the `.accepted` attribute will be `False` in the second case, and you won't get the redirect and success message. Change the first line to:

```
form = SQLFORM(db.membership)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `form = SQLFORM(db.Membership).process()` just change it to `form = SQLFORM(db.Membership)`

```
def signup():
   form = SQLFORM(db.Membership)
   form.add_button('Back', URL('index.html'))

   if form.process().accepted:
        session.flash = 'form accepted'
        redirect(URL('index.html'))
   elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'form has errors'
   else:
        response.flash = 'please fill the form'

   return locals()
```

By the way, my i ask why you're creating a new 'Membership' table ? Web2py Auth already deal with authentication and authorisation for you. Check [Access Control](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control) at Web2py's book.